# What is the background page while creating a new SharePoint List

Tags: list, library, design

When I create a SharePoint list, the page doesn't shows the right side bar.
However, creating a new SharePoint page reflects the right side bar.

Therefore would like to confirm as which background page does SharePoint uses while creating the List page.

Currently, all my List & Document Library page don't have the right side bar.

Comment: is it SharePoint 2013 ?

Comment: Yup, SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have used different master page for System master page and site master page.That is why it is coming different for both of them.

[image]

Comment: Amit,


In my case both pages are seattle

Comment: Interesting, I Just want the side bar to appear. wondering how can I copy the content from the page where it shows me and paste on the master page for the LIST

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20229/not-all-pages-have-a-side-navigation-on-the-left

Answer (score 0):

Below given URL of that page from where the list is going to be created.

```
http://serverURL/_layouts/15/new.aspx?FeatureId=%7B00bfea71%2Dde22%2D43b2%2Da848%2Dc05709900100%7D&ListTemplate=100&IsDlg=1
```

**The number 100 for `ListTemplate` represents the type of the list you are creating. here given URL is used to create a custom list.**

If you want to create a library than you can replace the number in `ListTemplate` parameter in the given URL.

**You can remove `&IsDlg=1` from the parameter to see the page within your SharePoint Master page as a normal page.**

Comment: Hardik,

I`m confused with your explanation.

Comment: Ohh.... What do I need to do now?

Comment: I had given you the page url from where list is going to be created.... & explain the parameters

Comment: Mate,

Not sure, how that helps to change the background page?

Comment: You asked about the background page which SharePoint uses while creating the list or library & I had given that answer... If you want to change the existing page than please mention it clearly in your answer...

Comment: Chill Hardik, you are sounding too out of this world!